# To update a widget, service is necessary?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I am developing a widget, which will display random tips every 30 seconds. Tips are fetched from server.
I have used alarm manager to do this.

I have used two approaches as given below.

First One: **Using Service.**

I have started an intent service from OnUpdate method of widget provider class. In the service I have initialized asynctask to get tips from server, then set alarm which will go off at 30 seconds from now,update widget with new tip and stopped the service.When the alarm goes off, it sends out an intent to start my intent service which i have started from OnUpdate. So the service will again initialize asynctask to get tip from server, sets alarm and stops. This will continue and tips is refreshed periodically.  When the widget is removed from home screen, i have cancelled the alram.

Second One: **Using Receiver**

Created a repeating alarm from onEnabled() method of widget provider class. When the alarm goes off it broad cast a custom intent. In the widget provider class I have defined a listner which will receive this intent. Once intent is received, initialized asynctask to get tips from server and update the widget with the new tips (code is written in onReceive() method.). The alarm is repeating every 30 seconds, so the intent will be received and tips are refreshed periodically. When the widget is removed from home screen, alarm is cancelled.

In Both cases, used alarm type as AlarmManager.RTC, so that it will not wake up the device, when alram goes off.

**I want to know is it necessary to write a service to update widget**? I mean which approach is better? And is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Krishna

Comment: Thanks rekire for your reply. I will reduce the update count.